# How to retrieve two data child to recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm working on an Android project in my university. I have a Firebase Realtime Database like this.

[image: Firebase]

I have a recyclerview which has both data from two child: pump and sensor(soilMoisture). Generally, it looks like this(in one card):

TextView (id:sensor) (name from sensor-> soilMoisture)
TextView (id:moisture) (moisture from sensor-> soilMoisture)
Textview (id:pump) (name from pump)
TextView (id:auto)(auto from pump)

(It's not different type of views, it just one cardview but need data from two child).
But I can only retrieve one child from Firebase to my Adapter. I can only show the pump name,auto (or sensor's) at once.

Here's my code:

**ActivityPump.java**

```
package com.example.gardbot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ActivityPump extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recview;
    myAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controlpump);
        recview=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recview);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("pump"), model.class).build();

        adapter= new myAdapter(options);
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

**model.java**

```
package com.example.gardbot;

public class model {
    String name,auto,waterLevel;

    model()
    {
    }

    public model(String name, String auto, String waterLevel) {
        this.name = name;
        this.auto = auto;
        this.waterLevel=waterLevel;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuto() {
        return auto;
    }

    public void setAuto(String auto) {
        this.auto = auto;
    }

    public String getWaterLevel() {
        return waterLevel;
    }

    public void setWaterLevel(String waterLevel) {
        this.waterLevel = waterLevel;
    }

}
```

**myAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.gardbot;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class myAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<model,myAdapter.myviewholder> {

    public myAdapter(@NonNull @NotNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull model model) {
        holder.pump.setText(model.getName());
        holder.pump.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.pump.isChecked())
                {
                    holder.linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        {

        };
    }
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow, parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }


    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CheckBox pump;
        LinearLayout linear;
        SwitchCompat switchstate;
        public myviewholder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pump=(CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pump);
            linear=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);
            switchstate=(SwitchCompat)itemView.findViewById(R.id.switchstate);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I get data from sensor (Firebase) to recyclerview (along with pump) as well? (Showing both data from 2 child in one recyclerview)

Comment: i did not understand what you want . the thing i understood is that you want to fetch and show the pump and sensor data . If you just show the data then you have to add another textview to show the sensor data . if you want one text view for two things to show then you should concatenate  like a string . otherwise it is overwriting the value .

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry for not describing it carefully.
I mean I have TextView for both pump and sensor as well (4 TextView). But I can only fetch one data child (from adapter) to recyclerview. I have 2 TextView for pump and another 2 for sensor but I can only show 2 TextView of pump (or 2 of sensor) at once ( I created another adapter for sensor). 
I mean I don't know how to show both pump and sensor(soilMoisture) data at once in Recyclerview(not mention the relation between them) with TextView for both of them. 
I may not understand it the right way or can you tell me another way to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an adapter from the FirebaseUI library. All adapters in this library are built to show only nodes from under a single path in the database. So they can either show the children of `sensor` **or** the children of `pump`, but they can't show the children of both nodes in a single list.

You will either have to change your data structure to have a single flat list of nodes, or you will have to create your own adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueEventListener` and filter though the pump data until you find the matching `pump` with `sensor`

For that, you will need to put this code (but you will need to set sensor id, for example: instead of "s0001", put "0001"):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pump").child("p" + model.getSensorId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String waterLevel = dataSnapshot.child("waterLevel").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 
    }
});
```

And also add a variable to your model:

`String sensorId;`

And then add the following to the sensor data: `sensorId`